# git-upload-pack not found while adding new repository to Eclipse Git

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I use Eclipse with GIT plugin. I try to add a new GitHub repository, by copying the GitHub URL to the clipboard, then going to the "Git Repositories" view and right-clicking "Paste Repository Path or URL".

I get the following error:

https://github.com/rothariel/aimnegochat: **https://github.com/rothariel/aimnegochat/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found**

This is strange, because I already have some repositories in this view...

Comment: Can you confirm you copied this ( https://github.com/rothariel/aimnegochat.git )? With `https://` in front, it is just the editor which cut it out

Comment: Ah, yes, I copied from the browser URL line, which didn't contain the ".git" extension. How could you deduce this from the cryptic error message?! Thanks!

Comment: I really have no idea! Probably I did the same mistake some time ago and it just popped into my mind :) BTW, I tried to translate my comment into an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From Erel's answer to my question in the comment section, it turned out the mistake was the copy of the wrong url. So, instead of copying the url provided by github, Erel copied the url in the navigation bar. The solution was to change the repository address to https://github.com/rothariel/aimnegochat.git

Comment: Works like a charm. That saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

For users of EGit/Eclipse who get the same error when clone from Visual Studio Online, be careful
the repo URL is not:
- https://[alt-name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/[your_repo]

the correct one is:
- https://[alt-name].visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/**_git/**[your_repo]

Answer (score 0):

I had this message before
service=git-upload-pack not found

Seems the gitlab user & password I used for that git was wrong.
I changed it to the right one and it worked just fine.

Yosi Lev